# How to transform the &amp; to & appearing in autocomplete dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

In my autocomplete drop down search `'&'` appearing as `'&amp;'` how to keep it as `'&'`

Here is my drop down php code

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
$term = str_replace(' ', '%', $term);
$qstring = "SELECT name as value, client_id FROM goa WHERE name LIKE '" . $term . "%' limit 0,5000";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);
$qcount = 0;
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id'] = (int) $row['client_id'];
        $row_set[] = $row; //build an array$qcount= $qcount + 1;}}echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
}
```

Comment: use `html_entity_decode();`

Comment: how to use it  in above code............

Comment: `html_entity_decode($row['value']);`

Comment: i am directly fetching data from the database ...in the database i have '&' character which displayed as '&amp;'....but really dont know how to use html_entity_decode();

Comment: @Saty wrote how to use it....what else do you need?

Comment: yes ...it worked....thanks again...

Comment: @Rasclatt I write it how to use!!

Comment: @Saty Yeah, that's what I said. I was saying that you demonstrated how to use it, the OP shouldn't have needed to ask any further how to use it because you told them.

Comment: I just provide hint to OP so that he can use it but it would better for  implement it on OP code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove `&amp` from string you can use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row['value'] = html_entity_decode($row['value']);
        $row['id'] = (int) $row['client_id'];
        $row_set[] = $row; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this `htmlentities` to this `html_entity_decode()`

So **final Code will** be

```
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
$term = str_replace(' ', '%', $term);
$qstring = "SELECT name as value, client_id FROM goa WHERE name LIKE '" . $term . "%' limit 0,5000";
$result = mysql_query($qstring);
$qcount = 0;
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row['value'] = html_entity_decode(stripslashes($row['value']));//change
        $row['id'] = (int) $row['client_id'];
        $row_set[] = $row; //build an array$qcount= $qcount + 1;}}echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
}
```

[`html_entity_decode()` example in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp)